# Can I combine data in multiple row into one row? - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to use data with multiple row in **IN** operator. 
so I think I have to combine into one row like

```
ids
------
19, 17
49, 48, 47, 46, 45
```

=>

```
ids
-----
19, 17, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45
```

Can I ask how to combine it?

Comment: What does `IN` have to do with this?

Comment: It seems implausible that this situation would arise within a normalised environment

Comment: Can you share your whole SQL query. It is easier to help when you understand the full context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details of what you want to achieve. But an aggregate function like GROUP_CONCAT might be what you need.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids) FROM YourTable;
```

Here's the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be16898e6d7464fb5f438e04660606df)